# How to manage iterative django migrations when working on same branch with other people

Tags: django, migration

I am working on a django project and many times i will iterate on a new model creating new migration files along the way.The migration file names are different but change parts of the same model. These migration files are also shared with other developers.What is the correct order of operations to execute in order to synchronize the changes with other developers working on the same branch and applying the migrations? I understand that reinitializing the db is a solution but arguably not a very clean one.

I have tried this sequence after deleting the last migration in the receiving end but it does not work as expected

```py
python manage.py migrate app_name XX #returns to the previous migration
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate # this creates issue because the relations-columns already exist
```

The next logical thing to do is

```py
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

However, this does not solve the issue because the **updated** changes are not reflected.

Lastly, I have also tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations --merge
```

but this does not find something to merge.

The error I am getting is:

```
Relation "foo" already exists
```

signifying that the table already exists in the db schema.

Comment: what exact error are you getting when you try to migrate?
Could you update your question with the error msg pls.

Comment: Updated the question. The issue is that the table has already been created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two migrations that are actually creating `foo` whatever that is. There are couple of ways around this. You can inspect the migration files manually and find the offending migration, delete it and all future ones (assuming there aren't any manual migration files created) and run `python manage.py makemigrations` again.

If you're not comfortable doing that, then you can try the steps below:

1. Login to the DB attached to the environment you're trying to deploy to (let's call this prod).
2. Execute the following query:

```sql
select * from django_migrations order by id desc;
```

This should show you the migrations actually applied to the DB in descending order. Take a note of the app and name.

3. Go to your codebase and delete all migrations that came after that point.
4. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` again.

This should create a fresh set of migrations without the conflict that you're seeing.

**WARNING: Make sure you don't have any custom migration files before doing this.** Providing you only create migration files using `python manage.py makemigrations`, this wouldn't be an issue.